# Modify the response so it routes the client to my Error.cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a http handler in my server side code.
All responses go through the handler. I'm implementing code that checks to see if the response to the client is a 2xx response, otherwise (i.e. 404) route to my custom error page.

Eventually, I'll have a different error page depending on certain criteria that I'm checking on the request and response, but first I just need to know how to reroute to a simple `error.cshtml` page in my views.

How do I modify the response so it routes the client to my `Error.cshtml` page (in views), instead of responding for example, with a `404`?

```
namespace Mymodels.Models
{
    public class myHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {            
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //inspects outgoing response to check if status code is 2xx
            {
                //do response work here since response is 2xx
            }
            else
            {
               //How do I modify the reponse to Error.cshtml page?, which is in my Views folder

            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you add this to else `throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");` and configuration will be    ` <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="views/Error.cshtml" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>`

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed I don't think that will work for me, because I'm going to reroute them to various error pages depending on the contents of the request. Meaning, I'm handling the 404 error by reading the request and rerouting them to a error page that will contain information on how to obtain the information they need. Thus it will be various error pages, which are custom to their request.

Comment: I think in these case you need to not use HTTP error code unless something related to like `404, 403,401` you need just return response with the needed html error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use `HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute`:

```
namespace Mymodels.Models
{
    public class myHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {            
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

             if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound) //if response is NOT 404
            {
                //do response work here since response is not 404
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect; //set status code to 302
                HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("customErrorRequestPage", "Home"); 

            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Application_Error handler in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();

    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

    if (httpException != null) {
        string action;

        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode()) {
            case 404:
                action = "HttpError404";
                break;
            case 500:
                action = "HttpError500";
                break;
            default:
                action = "HttpErrorGeneric";
                break;
        }

        RouteData routeData = new routeData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", action);
        routeData.Values.Add("Summary","Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("Description", ex.Message);
        IController controller = New ErrorController()
        controller.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    }
}
```